# python's json: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to load a string (the actual program read this line from a file and it is a very large file that I can not manually modify) formatted as a dictionary.

I need to convert the string line into a json object so I can check value of specific key, e.g. `myJson[Date]` .

This is the script:

```
import json

mystring = "{'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.39', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'}"


mystring = json.dumps(mystring)
myJson = json.loads(mystring)

print(str(myJson.keys()))
print(str(myJson))
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I suspect that the `mystring` format is not conforming and that the single quotes should be double quotes? Given that I have a large data, and I can not simply replace single colons with double one using simple search/replace as single colons may be included in the values which I should not modify. If this is the cause of the problem, is there any way to replace the colons of the key/value pair only without touching the colons in the values? I am hoping that this is not the problem.

Comment: What is this line for: `mystring = json.dumps(mystring)`? Besides your string is not valid JSON (single quotes instead of double).

Comment: Where did `mystring` come from? It looks like you took a perfectly good dict and converted it into a string. The correct course of action is most likely not to add more processing steps, but to remove an earlier, incorrect step.

Comment: If you're really stuck with this string, you may have to use something like `ast.literal_eval` or a permissive JSON parser. `json.dumps` will definitely not be part of the correct solution.

Comment: `mystring` is not valid JSON to begin with — it needs double quotes to be json.

Comment: You serialized your Python `str` object into a JSON string object. So when you deserialize it, it is going to be a string. As others have noted, your string doesn't actually contain valid JSON to begin with, but in any case, you almost certainly didn't mean to `json.dumps(mystring)` first. *That doesn't make any sense*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than dealing with the single quoted string and struggling to convert it into json, just use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) package to convert it into a valid dict.

```
import ast

mystring = "{'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.39', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'}"

my_dict = ast.literal_eval(mystring)
```

the result is:

```
> print(my_dict["Date"])
Fri, 19 Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

This code stores the string as a dictionary in a variable called "Tempvar"
From that variable you can just use the keys like a regular dictionary.

```
import json

mystring = "{'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.39', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'}"

exec("tempvar = " + mystring)
mystring = json.dumps(mystring)
myJson = json.loads(mystring)

print(str(tempvar['Date']))
print(str(myJson))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Yes json decoder likes double quotes for keys and values, and I think you can use python to do the replacement, try if applies:

```
mystring = "{'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.39', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'}"
json_string = mystring.replace("'", "\"")
d = json.loads(json_string)

dstring = json.dumps(d)
myJson = json.loads(dstring)

print(str(myJson.keys()))
```

Comment: Are you sure the `mystring.replace` will replace only the key/value commas? Not any other commas inside the value?

Comment: the replace command replaces single quotes with double quotes, not the commas.   You can print the result of the replace command only, to see how it works

Comment: Yes I mean quotes. that was a typo. But as I said, the data in the values may contain double quotes. This is dangerous to blindly replace quotes. Unless there isa method that can guarantee that only key/value quotes get replaces.

Comment: ohh I see your concern... ast.literal_eval is a more practical solution in this particular case

Comment: I mean inside the value, it is possible that I have single quotes that should remain. Example: `'Date': 'Fri, '19' Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT'`. I should not change the quotes in 19. Or possibly there will be double quotes like Example: `'Date': 'Fri, "19" Apr 2019 03:58:04 GMT'` which I do not know if will cause problems if I converted the single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: The problem with that string is that will be interpreted as two different values with something in the middle like 'Fri, ' 19 and ' Apr 2019... '.   The other case is easy to solve with an extra par of replacements